# Json Vs Conventional Technologies

Tags: json

We are having a site which are having bulk data like approx 50000 to 100000 records. I want to render this data in my site with paging of 10. Which Technology i should use for that. Performance is key thing of us. So should i use JSON to call web service and with help of JavaScript render data on page. and render the data or should i go for conventional Technologies like repeater or grid view. Which performance will be better.

Please suggest me which will be best?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sending and rendering 10 elements will be extremely fast regardless of the technology (JSON, full page refresh...)

What is important here is how the server will select those 10 elements out of 50k-100k records. Database software usually provides ways to quickly select a fixed number of elements from an indexed set, for instance.

Comment: Database are fully optimized withe everything like indexing etc. My concern is just about rendering html which will be fast json or traditional way

Comment: Your best bet is probably to use a high-performance template system on your server to render the ten elements as fast as possible, then send the HTML to the client over an AJAX channel, and have the client-side JavaScript insert the HTML into the document.

On a modern setup, the entire rendering phase regardless of the solution you choose should be close to a millisecond, probably even faster, and definitely too short to be observed by the user.

Answer (score 0):

If you store your 50-100k records in a text file, be it JSON or something else, then it has to scan the file to display a page of data, at least until the end of the page it's displaying. This does not scale.

While it will work "ok" with 50k or 100k records, once you reach, say, 10M, it will probably not. What you want is an indexed file which allows you to skip to the right record.

Comment: I am fetching data from sql server not the text file at a time it will only have 10 record out of 50k-100k records.